# topleft from surface rect dont accept new tuple value

Tags: python, pygame, tuples

I create pygame screen.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((330, 330))
```

Then i create an object of my own class and give him a tuple.

```py
mc = MyClass((10, 10))
```

This class has a **problem**. `topleft` from `surface` don`t accept new tuple value.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
        self.surface.get_rect().topleft = pos

        print(pos) # (10, 10)
        print(self.surface.get_rect().topleft) # (0, 0)
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *Surface* has no position and the rectangle is not an attribute of the *Surface*. **The `get_rect()` method creates a new rectangle object with the top left position (0, 0) each time the method is called**. The instruction

> ```py
> self.surface.get_rect().topleft = pos
> ```

only changes the position of an object instance that is not stored anywhere. When you do

> ```py
> print(self.surface.get_rect().topleft)
> ```

a new rectangle object will be created with the top left coordinate (0, 0).  You have to store this object somewhere. Then you can change the position of this rectangle object instance:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = pos
        print(self.rect.topleft)
```